# File System with Buildroot - Network & Keyboard issues

Tags: linux, keyboard, wget, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot to create a file system to run on a ARM target.

After a few attempts, I managed to make it work but I noticed a few problems.

- There wasn't any package manager.

It's impossible to install new utilities. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697129/buildroot-package-managment) question about opkg and I'll try to include it before the compilation of Buildroot

- The keyboard has been set with the us_US layout.

Is it possible to set the default keyboard layout to it_IT from buildroot instead of loading a configuration file with loadkmap in /etc/rcS?

- The ping and the wget commands show

> ping www.google.com
>
> ping: bad address google.com

Is there any specific configuration to do in Buildroot in order to solve this problem?

The network point is the most important.

Here is the output of the ifconfig command:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:25702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 MB)
```

Comment: *"There wasn't any package manager"* -- That's a known issue with using a simple build-tool.  Use OpenEmbedded or Yocto if you need to also build/manage packages.  The `ping` issue seems to be an incomplete network configuration of your board, and not a Buildroot issue.  Is the DNS server reachable?  Is the gateway address defined?

Comment: *"Here is the output of the ifconfig command:..."* -- That output would seem to indicate that you haven't configured your network interface at all.  There's only the loopback interface.  To access the Internet you need to configure the Ethernet interface, **eth0**.  Use `ifconfig -a` to see if you even have such an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding you question about keyboard layout: There is no way of setting the keyboard layout from the buildroot configuration.

You need to configure it from an init script under `/etc/init.d` (not in `/etc/init.d/rcS`; that script is solely used for running the scripts under `/etc/init.d/*` and should normally not be modified).

See e.g. http://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/tree/system/skeleton/etc/init.d/S40network for a simple template to base your init script on.