# Is there apt-get install in Buildroot?

Tags: linux, buildroot

Is there apt-get install analog command in Buildroot? I want to install some applicatin but how?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697129/buildroot-package-management) is helpful

Answer (score 5):

From [documentation of BuildRoot](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages):

> **Buildroot is not meant to be a distribution**
> (or rather, a distribution generator.) It is the opinion of most
> Buildroot developers that this is not a goal we should pursue.
>
> We prefer to push Buildroot in a direction that makes it easy
> (or even easier) to generate complete root filesystems. This is what
> makes Buildroot stands out in the crowd (among other things, of
> course!) **We believe that for most embedded Linux systems, binary
> packages are not necessary**, and potentially harmful.

So, It seems No! you can not do that by using **apt**. you need to directly add your packages [based on documentation](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-packages)

Answer (score -4):

By default in LINUX/UBUNTU Operating system is having apt-get installed so you can directly start using sudo apt-get install [Package Name that you want to install]